# File loop is wrongfully skipping files

Tags: vba, excel, loops, filepath

I have written the below code to loop through all the files in a directory and copy certain values from them and paste it back into the master file.

The problem that I am having is that the code never fully runs through all the files and I never get an error.

As shown in the picture the file names are depicted as 1 - #####, then 2 - ####, etc.

Sometimes there are multiple of the first number like in the picture there are two 1 - ###'s but the end numbers are still different.

The problem is that instead of going by the actual numerical order the code is using only the first number and going from 1, 10, 11, 100 and completely skipping the rest.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
Sub ReadDataFromCloseFile()
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim FileType As String
  Dim FilePath As String

  FileType = "*.xlsm*" 'The file type to search for
  FilePath = "\\filepath\" 'The folder to search

  Dim src As Workbook
  Dim OutputCol As Variant
  Dim Curr_File As Variant

  OutputCol = 9 'The first row of the active sheet to start writing to

  Curr_File = Dir(FilePath & FileType)

  Do Until Curr_File = ""
    ' OPEN THE SOURCE EXCEL WORKBOOK IN "READ ONLY MODE".
    Set src = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & Curr_File, True, True)

    Sheets("Reporting").Range("I7:I750").Copy

    Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, OutputCol).Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    OutputCol = OutputCol + 1

    ' CLOSE THE SOURCE FILE.
    src.Close False             ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
    Curr_File = Dir
  Loop
  Set src = Nothing

  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  ErrHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[Filepath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQygF.png)

Comment: Also, the loop does capture the multiple 1's and 10's.  It just always skips anything with 2-9 in it.

Comment: You have tried this after commenting out the `on error` ? At the moment you just silently return if something goes wrong.

Comment: Yeah I deleted that part from my code but it still doesn't error out on me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've no idea why it doesn't open the 2 to 9 files.  This version puts all the file paths into a collection and then steps through the collection.
It also does away with selecting the sheets before pasting, etc.

```
Sub ReadDataFromCloseFile()

    Dim FileType As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim colFiles As Collection
    Dim src As Workbook
    Dim tgt As Workbook
    Dim OutputCol As Variant
    Dim Curr_File As Variant

    Set colFiles = New Collection

    FileType = "*.xlsm*" 'The file type to search for
    FilePath = "\\filepath\" 'The folder to search

    EnumerateFiles FilePath, FileType, colFiles

    OutputCol = 9 'The first row of the active sheet to start writing to

    'If Master.xlsm is the book containing this code then use '=ThisWorkbook'
    Set tgt = Workbooks("Master.xlsm")

    For Each Curr_File In colFiles
        Set src = Workbooks.Open(Curr_File, True, True)

        src.Worksheets("Reporting").Range("I7:I750").Copy
        tgt.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, OutputCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        OutputCol = OutputCol + 1

        src.Close False

    Next Curr_File

End Sub

Sub EnumerateFiles(ByVal sDirectory As String, _
    ByVal sFileSpec As String, _
    ByRef cCollection As Collection)

    Dim sTemp As String

    sTemp = Dir$(sDirectory & sFileSpec)
    Do While Len(sTemp) > 0
        cCollection.Add sDirectory & sTemp
        sTemp = Dir$
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: For whatever reason this is skipping them as well an is doing the same ones as previously.  If I do it in a folder where the file names are regular 1,2,3,4,5 it works.  But this folder that has 1-####, 1-####, 2-### it doesn't.

Comment: I was able to modify this a little bit more and then it started working.  Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier for you to loop through the files using the below loop.

```
Sub LoopFiles()

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim Fldr As Folder
Dim Fl As File

'Loop through files in folder
For Each Fl In FSO.GetFolder(filePath).Files
    'Check for file type
    If Fl.Type = "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook" Then
        'Open file & do procedure
    End If
Next
Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this, but it keeps giving me a error.  Would you know how to incorporate the code I had into this??? I don't know how I can post what I had tried modifying it to since I can't post code in comments

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your variable OutputCol as an integer and not a variant.  If you know your data is always going to be a number, it's never a good idea to use a variant.  It takes more resources to execute the code and you don't know all of the internal logic that is going on behind the scenes.  It also gives you more control of the code's execution and probably won't give you headaches like this one. Only use a variant if you don't know what data you are going to output.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This should help with performance, but it doesn't fix the skipping issue.  I do appreciate the performance advice though!

Comment: I'll look at it some more and let you know what I see.